# Accessing the data / voice streams for the Android and iOS platforms

Tags: iphone, android, ios, iostream

I haven't done any work with the Android or iOS platforms, but I have recently been pitched a project and I'm trying to see if it is even feasible.

Is there currently API hooks in the iOS and Android platforms for accessing / manipulating the voice / data streams?  What I would like to do is encrypt all outgoing steams and decrypt all incoming streams before they reach and other processes that need that data.

I would assume that because the Android platform is open source one should be able to do this, it just may have to be hacked together. I'm more worried about iOS.

Thank you all for sharing your knowledge of this platforms with me,

Eric

Comment: How might this be different from either using a VPN or the encryption built into the 3G communication protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there currently API hooks in the iOS and Android platforms for accessing / manipulating the voice / data
>   streams?

On Android, no, sorry, that is not possible without custom firmware.

Answer (score 0):

It's just not possible on iOS. I can't imagine Apple ever giving you access to it, ever.

You've got a couple of options to do something like what you're talking about:

1. Use the built-in VPN features along with a VoIP app (either one you create or one that already exists). Your app won't have any control over enabling/disabling the VPN though.
2. Create a VoIP app (not an easy thing, but obviously Skype has done it) that communicates with other people over SSL.